# Разрешить и запретить EditText по нажатию одной кнопки

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, android-button

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите реализовать: по нажатию на Button я могу редактировать EditTest  setEnabled(true), а еще одно  нажатие блокирует EditText, т.е. setEnabled(false);

Comment: В чём состоит вопрос?

Comment: Когда нажимаю на кнопку, EditText можно редактировать, а когда еще раз нажимаю на кнопку, то EditText блокируется для ввода

Comment: код в вопросе должен быть в виде форматированного текста, а не скриншотом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awesomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      awesomeEditText.setEnabled(!awesomeEditText.isEnabled());
   }
});
```

Comment: Не получается, можешь пояснить код?

Comment: @ДанилФилиппов, что именно не получается? Ошибки или что? Дополни свой вопрос кодом

Comment: куда я должен сунуть строку  awesomeEditText.setEnabled(!awesomeEditText.isEnabled());

Comment: Ошибок нет, просто кнопка на второй клик не как не реагирует

Comment: @ДанилФилиппов, сувать туда же, где её разместил я. Приложите код к вашему вопросу, я понятия не имею, что у вас происходит в самом коде

Comment: Скрин прикрепил, List_1 List_2 и List_3 это EditText, который в разметке у меня недоступны для редактирования, по нажатию на кнопку я их могу редактировать. Теперь нужно по нажатию на кнопку опять их скрыть

Comment: @ДанилФилиппов, естественно у вас ничего не будет меняться - вы по клику постоянно устанавливаете для ваших `EditText` свойства `Enabled` в значение *true*. Я вам дал ведь в ответе рабочий код.

Comment: А как можно исправить?

Comment: @ДанилФилиппов, сделать так, как я вам описал в своём ответе. Если вы всё ещё не понимаете, что происходит - советую приступить к чтению литературы о разработке под Android

Comment: У меня в разметке должен быть добавлен android:enabled ??

Comment: @ДанилФилиппов, нет. Чтоб у вас всё заработало - вы должны сделать так, как написано в ответе, то есть при клике устанавливать значение свойства `Enabled` отличное от текущего

Comment: где я должен прописать Enable. Или весь код состоит из одной строчки?

Comment: @ДанилФилиппов, весь код состоит из того, что я написал в ответе. `List_1.setEnabled(!List_1.isEnabled())` и так с каждым

Comment: Все, я разобрался, спасибо большое